# Escape character issue in "run keyword if" in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework, string

This script is not working as the string contains single quotes (') and double quotes (") and comparing the string is not working in this case.

```
${Key1}=      set variable     It\'s in \"Detailing\": The Perfect Gift
${KEY_FLAG}   run keyword if   "${Key1}"=="It\'s in \"Detailing\": The Perfect Gift"        set variable        X1
log     ${Key_FLAG}
```

Any solution ?

Comment: Can you please fix the formatting of the code. It's impossible to see the indentation and whitespace unless you mark up the code as code.

Answer (score 1):

The condition passed to `Run keyword if` needs to be a valid python expression after substituting.

The easiest solution is to do one or both of the following:

- use triple quotes to quote the string
- use robot's ability to directly use the variable as `$Key1` rather than `${Key1}`

Also, it's not necessary to escape the quotes when calling `Set Variable`. They are harmless but make the code harder to read.

For example, the following example uses both techniques and should pass:

```
*** Variables ***
${KEY_FLAG}  ' and "

*** Test Cases ***
Example
    ${Key1}=  set variable  It's in "Detailing": The Perfect Gift ${KEY_FLAG}

    run keyword if  $Key1=='''It's in "Detailing": The Perfect Gift ' and "'''
    ...  pass execution  the condition is true
    fail  the condition is false
```